# use variable from other function in same class codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i'm newbie codeigniter programmer.

i want to use function and all variable from this function to another function in same class controller. this my code

```
function page()
{   

    $page_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $page_details = $this->m_module->submenu($page_id)->row_array();
    $data['title']= $page_details['sub_title'];
    $data['menu'] = $page_details['title'];
    $data['submenu'] = $page_details['sub_title'];
    $data['link'] = $page_details['sub_target'];
    $data['page_id'] = $page_id;
}

function employee()
    {
        $data['employee']= $this->m_module->employee()->result_array();
        $this->page();      
        $this->template->display($data['link'],$data);
    }
```

the problem is variable function page() can't call in function employee().

this i get at browser

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: link

Filename: controllers/Module.php

Line Number: 39
```

please help.

Thank you

Comment: You need to set a private variable inside the containing class e.g. private link and then set it inside your page function like $this->link = $data['link'] and then use $this->link to reference it in employee.

Comment: can you give example from my code?

Comment: I've added an example below. Is your code inside a CI class, something like below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your method like the following

```
private function page() {
$page_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$page_details = $this->m_module->submenu($page_id)->row_array();

return [
    'title' => $page_details['sub_title'];
    'menu' => $page_details['title'];
    'submenu' => $page_details['sub_title'];
    'link'=> $page_details['sub_target'];
    'page_id' => $page_id;
];
```

}

```
private function employee() {
  $data = $this->page();
  $data['employee']= $this->m_module->employee()->result_array();
 $this->template->display($data['link'],$data);
}
```

The reason you were not getting was because your method was not returning as value.

Comment: thank you brother, but now i have problem, variable $data['employee'] can't call in view page. error this code 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: employee

Filename: human_capital/employee.php

Line Number: 24

i want to array $data['employee'] at view page like this

<?php $no =1; foreach($employee AS $emp_list) { ?>

Comment: check the updated code.

Comment: thank you so much Bro. this very helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class variable to pass the value of link between functions

```
<?php
    class MyController extends CI_Controller {
        private $link;

        public function page($data){
            $this->link = $data['link'];
        }

        public function page(){
            echo $this->link;
        }

    }
?>
```